# PHP output altered when variable present

Tags: php, url, caching, variables, magento

I have the weirdest thing happening on my site. My PHP script is outputting different content depending upon whether there's a query mark (?) present or not. It doesn't matter if there is a query string present after the mark or not - the simple presence of the "?" changes the output. I didn't code anything to even look for that query mark let alone do anything differently depending upon if it found it or not. It's driving me nuts! Could there be an explanation for why this is happening?

Here are sample links: 1) [...html](http://www.qualitysewing.com/class-calendar-northgate.html), 2) [...html?](http://www.qualitysewing.com/class-calendar-northgate.html?) (The most significant changes occur in the month of March.)

EDIT: Sorry, I didn't think the code would be very helpful, and there's a ton of it. I don't think you'll be able to "recreate the issue" since this code depends on Magento to run, but here it is. (I had to strip out a lot of comments to get it under the size requirements.)

EDIT: Code removed since it wasn't useful or pertinent to finding the answer.

Comment: Post some code that we can use to recreate the issue

Comment: Can you point us to the URL so we can see the difference? Or post some sample outputs here? "changes the output" is too generic to allow an educated guess. Some bits of code would also be useful.

Comment: post the code that is doing the DB query to get the calendar

Comment: You want us to speculate? Show us code. Describe the environment. *Something.*

Comment: I don't even see how the content is different in these examples without viewing the source code...

Comment: Sorry, guys - I just thought that since I wasn't looking for the query string anywhere in my code that the code wouldn't be relevant. I appreciate your efforts to help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a caching problem.  Try clearing it out...

> http://kb.siteground.com/article/How_to_clear_the_cache_in_Magento.html
>
> Magento keeps its cache in /var/cache located inside the Magento installation directory. So, for example, if your Magento is installed in your main public_html folder, the cache will be in public_html/var/cache.

Comment: That's a very good point. I just installed TinyBrick's [LightSpeed](http://www.tinybrick.com/improve-magentos-slow-performance.html) caching extension, so that might be what's causing it. It would have created a new cached page from more current data when the URL was changed. Without the URL change to generate a new page it's showing me old data. Genius!

Comment: Yep, that did it. Whenever there's something really weird like that I need to remember CLEAR THE CACHE! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, that was not what was happening. The location remains unchanged. But it has to be one of the options that can be passed in by URL that is getting overritten. Check to see what option might make give you the same output as the non-parameter query.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the code. I tried this and it didn't help. The thing is, I'm not using GET variables at all. That $selected_location variable is just a regular old variable just like any other and I don't see how any change in the URL would (or should) effect that.

Comment: I looked a little more closely and saw the location is remaining unchanged. See my edit for further a debugging tip.